# Android View.GONE not working as intended on rare occasions

Tags: android, view

I've been seeing an issue in an app I'm working on relating to `views` being `visible` when they shouldn't be and I was wondering if anyone had seen similar.

I have a `fragment` viewed from a `viewPager`,  that `fragment` has a `base layout`,  in that base layout I include a banner style area with some info in it and a `button`,  the layout is defaulted to `GONE` in the `XML`,  like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/usage_swipe_container"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/usage_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@color/background_colour">

            <include layout="@layout/layout_in_question"
                android:id="@+id/layout_in_question_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            .... Normal Stuff in layout


        </ScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This view is only set to `VISIBLE` in very select circumstances. However some users are seeing it outside of those circumstances based on a response from a server call, its a very low `percentage` of users who are seeing it when they shouldn't ( in the region of 0.001% ),  the server team insist its not them so I'm trying to ascertain if there are any known `android` issue or `"hacks"` that allow this sort of thing. The App supports `API 15` and up and we're currently using support `libs 25.3.0`.

Has anyone seen behavior like this before?  are there `developer options` on some devices that `"show all views"` or Modded OS's that allow it?

Edit:  While I cant share full code snippets due to NDA,  I have 2 locations the view can be enabled,  both call the same method.

```
private View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         ViewGroup container, 
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    setupBanner();
}

/**
  * OTTO event based on server response
  */
@Subscribe
public void receiveEvent(BannerEvent event)
{
    setupBanner();
}

public void setupBanner() {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (shouldShowBanner()) {                   
       findViewById(R.id.layout_in_question_id).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

shouldShowBanner returns a boolean which is either true/false depending on what the server responded with.

Comment: add your java code where you are showing and hiding this view.

Comment: you probably thought of this, but you never know: have you considered setting the view to GONE in the code as well if shouldShowBanner() returns false? Just in case the View is being reused? (I.e. add an else { view.setVisibility(GONE); }).

Comment: kazume,  that was my next step,  for a hotfix but the feature has been removed instead so I cant test it out.